# python naive string token matcher

Tags: python, string, string-matching

I've written a very naive token string search matcher.  It's a little too naive though, as with the following code, it would bring back every artists in the artists list, due to how **'a r i z o n a'** is tokenised.

```
import collections
import re

def __tokenised_match(artist, search_artist):
        matches = []
        if len(re.split(r'[\\\s/-]', search_artist)) > 1:
            a = [artist.sanitisedOne, search_artist]
            bag_of_words = [ collections.Counter(re.findall(r'\w+', words)) for words in a]
            sumbags = sum(bag_of_words, collections.Counter())
            print(sumbags)
            for key, value in sumbags.items():
                if len(re.findall(r'\b({k})\b'.format(k=key), search_artist)) > 0 and value > 1:
                    matches.append(artist)

        if len(matches):
            return matches


artists = [
{ 'artist': 'A R I Z O N A', 'sanitisedOne': 'a r i z o n a'},
{ 'artist': 'Wutang Clan', 'sanitisedOne': 'wutang clan'}
]

search_artist = 'a r i z o n a'

for artist in artists:
    print(__tokenised_match(artist, search_artist))
```

this'll create a sumbags like this:

> Counter({'a': 4, 'r': 2, 'i': 2, 'z': 2, 'o': 2, 'n': 2})
>
> Counter({'a': 2, 'wutang': 1, 'clan': 1, 'r': 1, 'i': 1, 'z': 1, 'o': 1, 'n': 1})

this is kind of edge casey, but i wonder how i can tighten up against this kind of edge case.  it would be fine for 'wutang clang' to match, but when it's single letters like this... it's a little much and will bring back every artist due to a matching twice.

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem is that you return success on only a single match.  This will kill your accuracy for any artist with an easily matched token in the name.  We could tune your algorithm for matching a certain percentage of words, or for doing a bag-of-letters, intersection-over-union ratio, but ...

I recommend that you use something a bit stronger, such as [string similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric), which is easily found in Python code.  Being already packaged, it's *much* easier to use than coding your own solution.